# Transforming this integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Here is the integral. $0 < r < 1$

$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1-r^2}{1 + r^2 - 2r\cos{\varphi}} d\varphi$

I need to find a closed path In the complex plane I can rewrite this as.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  So $r$ is fixed and you need to interpret the integral as a path integral in the complex plane?  Try a circle centered at 0 with radius $r$.

Comment: Also, with $z:= re^{i\varphi}$, the denominator is $(1-z)(1-\overline{z})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "integrating variable" is $\varphi$, so you can take the numerator $1-r^2$ out of it, and focus on rewriting $$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{1}{1+r^2-2r\cos{\varphi}}d\varphi$$ over $\mathbb{C}$. As Dzoooks pointed out, the denominator is $(1-z)(1-\bar{z})$, however you want to eliminate the derivative of your curve, that comes along with the definition of complex integration. Dividing by $iz$ will do. So, taking $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z)(1-\bar{z})iz}$$and $\gamma(\varphi)=re^{i\varphi}$, the integral on $\mathbb{C}$ equals$$\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz.$$Let's check it out:$$\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(1-re^{i\varphi})(1-re^{-i\varphi})ire^{i\varphi}}ire^{i\varphi}d\varphi=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{r^2-2r\cos{\varphi}+1}d\varphi$$ as we wished.